# Python broken links after BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, windows, beautifulsoup

I'm a newbie to Python. Just installed it for Windows and try to HTML scraping.
Here's my test code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = 'text <a href="Transfert.php?Filename=myfile_x86&version=5&param=13" class="nav" style="color: #000000" title = "">Download</a> text'
print(html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

This code returns collected but broken link:

```
Transfert.php?Filename=myfile_x86&version=5¶m=13
```

[image]
How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you want as output?

Comment: Normal link text without string formatting to symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are feeding the parser invalid HTML, the correct way to include &
>   in a URL in a HTML attribute is to escape it to `&amp;`

Simply change `&` to `&amp;`

```
html = 'text <a href="Transfert.php?Filename=myfile_x86&amp;version=5&amp;param=13" class="nav" style="color: #000000" title = "">Download</a> text'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

**Output:**

```
Transfert.php?Filename=myfile_x86&version=5&param=13
```

The reason why it works with `html5lib` and `lxml` is because some parsers can handle broken HTML better than others. As mentioned by [`Goyo`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142055/goyo) in the comments, you can't prevent other people from writing broken HTML :)

This is a great answer to your question that explains it in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26073147/4796844.